# Как можно соединить "милый" и "жалкий" в одно предложение или словосочетание?

Tags: выбор-слов, словосочетания

На иностранном языке нашёл небольшое предложение, заключающее в себе слово "милый" в значении "жалкий"

Интересует подобный аналог в русском языке

Значение не должно присваиваться интонацией говорящего

Comment: Милый и жалкий по смыслу противоположны. Милый - это проявивший жалость к кому-то. Жалкий - тот к кому можно проявить милосердие. Милый и жалкий одновременно без сарказма вряд ли получится. Прелесть и милый - это не одно и тоже, прелесть это то, что льстит, то есть лжет, лжемилость.

Answer (score 1):

> Какая прелесть

Содержит оба значения

Answer (score 0):

Смазливенький? Это скорее разговорное слово, но без контекста тяжело выбрать другое.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, "беспомощный".